# Жирность линии для road.local Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать жирной линию для `featureType:"road.local"`

[image: google map]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [мастер стилей](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com) от Google.

Comment: спасибо огромное!)

Comment: Заходите еще )))